# Magento2 : How To Add New Words To Arabic Language Pack ar_SA.csv File

Tags: magento2, csv, language

Hello I want to add new words to already available arabic language pack csv file.

Can anyone tell me how i can add new words?

Answer (score 2):

You want to add new words to already available arabic language pack csv file, then you can open arabic language pack csv file `ar_SA.csv` and add your new words in ar_SA.csv file which you have to need and save csv file. Below is the sample words for reference example.

`"Your word","Arabic translation word"`

**Run below command:**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Hope it help!

Comment: i already tried but i can't get translated word

Comment: You are able to translate Other existing words from ar_SA.csv ?

Comment: yes all other words are translated but new one is not traslated

Comment: Add below line in ar_SA.csv 
"Your word", "كلمتك"

And then run command step by step:
php bin/magento s:up;
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f

Comment: i think we can also create ar_SA.csv  in app/code/vendor/extension/i18n and add new word to that file but still i can't get result

Comment: Have run the command.
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: I tried the above steps but Arabic words are showing as like this in my website  ??? ?? ????